# user location GPS coordinates when no internet

Tags: iphone, ios

For my app i need to access the GPS latitude and longitude coordinates when there is no internet connection in device. I used CLLocation to achieve this. But when i switch off the wifi and internet in device locationmanager is showing

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError %@", error);

}
```

The error i got is Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "the Operation could't be completed"

Once i get the proper user location how to refresh the app when the user moves from the current location?

I have downloaded the code of this tutorial http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/ but i got the same error.

Anyone please let me know how to achieve the GPS when offline, no internet.
Thanks

Comment: GPS info do not need network, make sure you enabled GPS for your app &  sometimes you can't get GPS in the room, try somewhere wild

Comment: But I saw the GPS in some other apps its working.How to enable theGPS for my app?

Comment: is there a alertview poped up that ask the permission of the location service first time you use GPS service?   or you can goto the setting page to check

Comment: No it didn't ask for permission as alertview and i checked location services is on for my app in settings.

Comment: I have downloaded this tutorial code and checking i got similar error http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/

Comment: @adali I am facing the same problem. I also want the same result, fetching user location when there is no internet connection but coudn't find anything effective.

Comment: @adali I have tested in free space above my building but i got the same error

Comment: whatbdo you mean exactly with offline?

Comment: @AlexWien That is even if you do not have an internet connection and no wifi connection but still it should update you with current location.

Comment: Look at the answer of Norbert

Answer (score 1):

The Basics of How Location Services Determines Your Location
Apple iOS uses a three-stage algorithm in order to determine your location:

1. Assisted Global Positioning System (A-GPS)
2. Crowdsourced Wi-Fi
3. Cellular network search

These three stages are used in descending order of priority. In other words, iOS first attempts to fix your location by using a GPS satellite link. If it is unable to acquire a satellite, iOS fails over to Wi-Fi. If you are not connected to a Wi-Fi local area network (WLAN), then iOS uses cell tower data. If all of the above fail, then you receive an error message such as what you see in the following figure.

Assisted GPS (A-GPS) shortens the time that it typically takes for a GPS client device to acquire a connection to a satellite. For instance, my morning runs are sometimes delayed by several minutes while I wait for my Garmin GPS training watch to connect to a satellite. Imagine how painful it would be to wait several minutes for your iPhone to make a GPS connection!

Essentially, your iDevice caches periodic snapshots of satellite data in order to speed up connection time. Obviously, you will observe the snappiest GPS performance when you are outside and away from sources of interference such as tall buildings or even the interior of your vehicle.

Crowdsourced Wi-Fi means that your iDevice again caches information not only regarding the WLAN to which you are currently connected, but also regarding any other WLANs within range of your device. By storing WLAN service set identifiers (SSIDs) and media access control (MAC) address information locally, this allows iOS location services to pinpoint your location much faster through triangulation.

The idea is that if iOS detects that you are connected to your home WLAN and it already has the global positioning coordinates of that location, location services can display your location without having to work through GPS connection or Wi-Fi triangulation.

Cellular Network Search involves the notion of “triangulation” again, this time with iOS using cached information regarding your nearby cellular towers. By the way, triangulation is a geometry principle that determines the location of a point by measuring angles to it from known points at either end of a fixed baseline. For instance, iOS can approximate your location by measuring distances between your iDevice and a number of cell towers that are nearby.

Comment: this is per theory but practically what changes i need to acquire the userlocation? I tested in the free wild space but i got the error locationdidfail error..

Comment: check that you actually have a valid WiFi and 3G connection and go to settings and reset your location services 3) reset your network settings

Comment: In wifi it works fine. But when i turn off the wifi it doesnt works.

Comment: So, you want to identify change location in offline also?

Comment: Yes i need to get the userlocation and change location in offline.

Comment: I don't think it possible. If you will go through theory once. you can get better idea how GPS is working for iOS..

Comment: I have seen many apps capturing geolocation when it is in offline mode in this same device.

Comment: @user2339310 you missed 1b) non assisted GPS

Comment: @Cintu I am also facing the same issue in tracking user location via Wifi. Can you please help me out through source code in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
```

Comment: depends what you mean with offline mode. in flight mode it does not work. in wilderness without gsm it works. in civilized regions it is difficult to see a sattelite while you dont have gprs access.

Comment: Is that i need to stopupdatelocation when it comes inside didUpdateToLocation ? If i dont stopupdatelocation it is leading to didfailwitherror

Comment: @AlexWien I have added the above code but still same problem.

Comment: Let's examine your problem deeper: `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError %@", error);
    NSLog(@"code: %@", [error code]);}`