# Objective - C - Current State from GPS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gps

I have used CLLocationManager to get the current GPS coordinates of a user.

**I need to get the current state where it is.**

With internet:

```
CLGeocoder *gc = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[gc reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemark, NSError *error)
{
  if(!placemark){
    /* handle error */
  }else{
    CLPlacemark *pm = placemark[0];
    NSLog(@"%@", pm.administrativeArea);
  }
}];
```

**Is there any way I could find out what the state where the user is without internet?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [user location GPS coordinates when no internet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272536/user-location-gps-coordinates-when-no-internet)

Comment: No. This is totally different issue.

Comment: I need to know the state of the current location. The location I already have.

Comment: oh sorry, but how to understand your question then? `Is there any way I could find out what the state where the user is without internet?` doesn't this ask for offline GPS access?

Comment: ah ok, but what state are you talking about? a country?

Comment: or a state in the united states?

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, I'll try an answer though.

Generally if you're asking if you can use the (reverse) geocoding API of `CLGeocoder` when the device is offline, the answer is **no**, as stated [here in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/index.html):

> The computer or device must have access to the network in order for
>   the geocoder object to return detailed placemark information.
>   Although, the geocoder stores enough information locally to report the
>   localized country name and ISO country code for many locations. If
>   country information is not available for a specific location, the
>   geocoder may still report an error to your completion block.

If with *state*, you mean a *country* or a *nation*, you at least have the option to hardcode a list of all the world's countries' coordinates in your app (or maybe you can find one online...) and use the location data to calculate the state... sounds like a lot of effort, but would solve your problem...